# Incrementing a variable in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm

Can anybody help me in incrementing value of a variable suppose by 5 in LLVM IR by a LLVM pass.
This is my instruction present which i want to increment

```
%1 = load i32* %k, align 4
  %inc = add nsw i32 %1, 1
store i32 %inc, i32* %k, align 4
```

In place of 1 in %inc(add) instruction how to replace it by 5.

I tried identifying Load instruction by

```
if(LoadInst *ld=dyn_cast<LoadInst>instruction)
```

and then

```
Value *Five = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), 5);
```

and then replacing add instruction by my new instruction

```
Instruction *in=BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add,ld,Five,"inc",some instruction);
```

I tried casting ld instruction to Value also, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `I` is the instruction iterator it would look something like

```
 if(I->getOpcode()== Instruction::Add)
      I->setOperand(1,Val *)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.But is not correct as we need L value.

Comment: How about I->setOperand(operandNo, Value *) ?. I used something similar not long ago and it worked, hopefully would work for you too

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope you up vote it if found useful